# C program to determine temperature conversions not working

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to create a program that asks the user what conversion the user wants to do, then scans for the number they want to convert, then does the conversion and spits it out.

Here are the instructions that include desired outputs:

Building on assignment one, create a program to with the choice of convert Celsius to Fahrenheit or Fahrenheit to Celsius using “ifelse” statement to chose which conversion you want to use. Be sure to include the correct header in your .C file.  Use the K and R formatting.  Name your file “first Initial last name-assingment2.c”   ex: “rgalus-assingment2.c” Below is what I expect the program output to look like:

```
Enter 1 to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
Enter 2 to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
Enter 0 to exit

1
10
10 degrees Celsius is equal to 50 degrees Fahrenheit

Enter 1 to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
Enter 2 to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
Enter 0 to exit

2
32
32 degrees Fahrenheit equals 0 degrees Celsius

Enter 1 to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
Enter 2 to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
Enter 0 to exit

0

“exit the program”
```

My issue is that while it will scan my choice, the program ends before I can enter a number to convert.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double userConversionChoice;
    double CelsiusToFahrenheitResult;
    double FahrenheitToCelsiusResult;
    double userConversionNumber;

    printf("Enter 1 to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit\n");
    printf("Enter 2 to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius\n");
    printf("Enter 0 to exit\n");

    scanf("%d", userConversionChoice);

    if (userConversionChoice == 1) {

        scanf("%d", userConversionNumber);
        CelsiusToFahrenheitResult = (1.8 * userConversionNumber) + 32.0;

        printf("%d degrees Celsius equals %d degrees Fahrenheit", userConversionNumber, CelsiusToFahrenheitResult);

        }
        else {

        if (userConversionChoice == 2) {
            scanf("%d", userConversionNumber);
            FahrenheitToCelsiusResult = (userConversionNumber - 32.0) / 1.8;

            printf("%d degrees Fahrenheit equals %d degrees Celsius", userConversionNumber, FahrenheitToCelsiusResult);
        }
            else {
                printf("exit the program");
            }
        }




    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Pass a pointer to scanf. Make sure the variable type matches the formatted type. And crank up the compiler warning level.

Comment: This `userConversionChoice` should be of `int` type not of `double` type, similarly `userConversionNumber` since you are using `%d` as a format specifier. Compile with `-Wall` & analyze the warnings. And the `scanf("%d", userConversionChoice);` ==> `scanf("%d", &userConversionChoice);` etc

Comment: @Bathsheba how does one pass a pointer?

Comment: Use the address-of operator &.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate issues are:

- `scanf` takes pointers to variables (`&x`), not variables. That's because a normal function call `f(x)` cannot modify `x` (arguments are passed by value).
- The `%d` conversion specifier reads an integer (and expects a corresponding `int *` argument). Your variables are of type `double`, so either you need to change them to `int` or use `%lf`.
- Similarly, `printf` `%d` expects an `int`, not a `double`. The format specifier for `double` is `%f`.
- You should check the return value when you use `scanf` to make sure a value was read successfully. `scanf` returns the number of input items assigned.

Thus:

```
int userConversionChoice;
if (scanf("%d", &userConversionChoice) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to read input\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;  // EXIT_FAILURE is in <stdlib.h>
}
```

```
double userConversionNumber;
if (scanf("%lf", &userConversionNumber) != 1) {
```

```
printf("%.2f degrees Celsius equals %.2f degrees Fahrenheit", userConversionNumber, CelsiusToFahrenheitResult);
```

---

In the long term, I recommend avoiding `scanf` for user input altogether. It is hard to use correctly, it makes for confusing user interfaces (e.g. if a user just hits enter, your program will sit there seemingly frozen, but actually still waiting for input in `scanf`), and it's hard to recover from errors.

For more intuitive behavior, read whole lines of input (using e.g. `fgets`) and convert them afterwards (using e.g. `sscanf` or `strtod` / `strtol`):

```
char buf[200];

...
printf("enter a number: ");
fflush(stdout);
if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    return 0;  // end-of-input was reached
}
double num = strtod(buf, NULL);  // convert input to number
```

Answer (score 1):

`userConversionNumber` is a `double`. You are reading into it using `%d` which is the conversion specifier for integers. 
And you are not using the `&` (address of) operator when reading into it.

```
scanf("%d", userConversionChoice);
```

So define `userConversionChoice` as an `int` and read the input this way:

```
scanf("%d", &userConversionChoice);
```

Behaviour of scanf:

> The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

So it is good practice to check the return value of `scanf` before further processing.

Comment: Yeah, new programmers don't usually do that.

Comment: How would checking the return value help here? It can't check if the conversion specifier matches the datatype correctly, it just checks if the input is valid for the spceifier.

Comment: Of course, in this cause, `userConversionChoice` is either `1` or `2` or it does nothing, but that does not mean checking the return isn't necessary or wouldn't help. If the return were properly checked and a warning or error issued in the event of `EOF`, or a *matching* or *input* failure, proper error handling would help not only with isolating any other problems, but insure that there was at least valid integer data present in the comparison (which would avoid UB if `userConversionChoice` was not previously initialized)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of scanf (and printf) is incorrect.

The format string must match the type of parameter you are using.  You can get away with this on printf() sometimes, but not scanf().

For scanf(), you must also pass the *address-of* (i.e.: a pointer to) the variable you wish to store into.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int    userConversionChoice;
    double CelsiusToFahrenheitResult;
    double FahrenheitToCelsiusResult;
    double userConversionNumber;

    printf("Enter 1 to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit\n");
    printf("Enter 2 to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius\n");
    printf("Enter 0 to exit\n");

    printf("Choice> ");
    scanf("%d", &userConversionChoice);

    if (userConversionChoice == 1) 
    {
        printf("Temperature> ");
        scanf("%lf", &userConversionNumber);

        CelsiusToFahrenheitResult = (1.8 * userConversionNumber) + 32.0;

        printf("%0.2lf degrees Celsius equals %0.2lf degrees Fahrenheit", userConversionNumber, CelsiusToFahrenheitResult);
    }
    else if (userConversionChoice == 2) 
    {
        printf("Temperature> ");
        scanf("%lf", &userConversionNumber);

        FahrenheitToCelsiusResult = (userConversionNumber - 32.0) / 1.8;

        printf("%0.2lf degrees Fahrenheit equals %0.2lf degrees Celsius", userConversionNumber, FahrenheitToCelsiusResult);
    }
    else 
    {
         printf("exit the program");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Obviously there's some room here for optimisation, since there's two lots of code inputting the temperature.

Comment: `scanf` `%f` takes `float *`, not `double *`.

Comment: @melpomene - yes you're right, it should be %lf (fixed). But if you wanted to support pre-C99, %f was ok for both.  ;)

Comment: `printf` `%lf` has undefined behavior in C89/C90. Your code requires C99+ (where `%lf` is equivalent to just `%f`).

Comment: @melpomene - technically, the `%0...` is not a *field-width* modifier, it is a *Flag Character* that indicates the value should be *zero-padded*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin D'oh, you're right. Corrected comment: Your code tells `printf` to pad the output with `0` characters, but does not specify a field width, so no padding is done in the first place.

Comment: Ah -- that just let's us know you're human `:)` -- and I agree, its use there is questionable at best.

Comment: I like to use the "%0.2lf" because it's explicit that the whole digits aren't specified (rather than just forgotten about).  I agree it's redundant.